# Jira API django connection adapters error

Tags: python, django, atlassian-python-api

Not sure what this django error is trying to tell me. Using a library called `atlassian-python-api`.

If I hardcode that URL into the jira object, a request is sent to the Jira api and there is no error. If I do it via postman and a viewset, it errors with:

```
No connection adapters were found for "['https://uk- 
ssdo.atlassian.net']/rest/agile/1.0/board?maxResults=50"
```

i.e

```
    jira = Jira(
    url='https://uk-ssdo.atlassian.net/',
    username='paul.macdonald@uk-ssdo.net',
    password='<password>',
    cloud=True,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the values being passed to the `Jira` object were wrapped in a `list` type and referencing the index 0 solved the 'No connection adapters were found' error.

```
        jira = Jira(
        url=details.jira_instance[0],
        username=details.username[0],
        password=details.password[0],
        cloud=details.is_cloud,
    )
```